# How to define a loss function that needs to input numpy array(not tensor) when build a tensorflow graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to add a constraint option in my loss function. The definition of this constraint option needs numpy array type as input. So, I can not define it as a tensor type as a graph node in tensorflow. How can I define this part in graph so as to join in the network optimization?

Comment: What does it need that requires a numpy array type? I imagine most properties defined for numpy arrays have analogs in Tensors. Also I'm not sure it's possible to use something other than a Tensor as input; could be wrong.

Comment: @Engineero, I want to use a SimpleITK library function to calculate a loss option based on  the output of GAN model. It needs numpy array type as input. I do not know how to use these functions when I define the loss function, they needs numpy array type as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operations done on numpy arrays cannot be automatically differentiated in TensorFlow. Since you are using this computation as part of loss computation, I assume you want to differentiate it. In this case, your best option is probably to reimplement the constraint in TensorFlow. The only other approach I can think of is to use [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd) in conjuction with TF. This seems possible - something along the lines of evaluate part of the graph with TF, get numpy arrays out, call your function under autograd, get gradients, feed them back into TF - but will likely be harder and slower.

If you are reimplementing it in TF, most numpy operations have easy one-to-one corresponded operations in TF. If the implementation is using a lot of control flow (which can be painful in classic TF), you can use eager execution or [py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/py_func).